# springboot mongodb connection failure exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm getting an exception on authenticating Mongo Credentials.

I'm trying to build a REST API using spring boot with using Mongo db. I'm receiving this exception while creating a collection on my custom created database named "abc".

It states that "Failed to execute CommandLineRunner" and it caused by

```
"Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='abc', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}"
```

This is the entire stacktrace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-16T13:42:45.889+05:30 ERROR 12852 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:773) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.example.abc.AbcApplication.main(AbcApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='abc', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2932) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1538) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1334) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1260) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.insert(SimpleMongoRepository.java:228) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy83.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.abc.AbcApplication.lambda$runner$0(AbcApplication.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='abc', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:270) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.lambda$authenticate$0(SaslAuthenticator.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:277) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.finishHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:85) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:209) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:55) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:534) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openWithConcurrencyLimit(DefaultConnectionPool.java:895) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:836) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:177) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:166) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:97) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:375) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$1(OperationHelper.java:357) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:383) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:356) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$execute$1(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:181) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:202) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:76) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1024) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:475) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:458) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:452) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$16(MongoTemplate.java:1544) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:600) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.1.0.jar:4.1.0]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:443) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:365) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:224) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 60 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue and i observed that it triggered once i updated form spring boot 3.0 to spring boot .31

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if u are trying to connect to remote server, check if server ip is added to [configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04)

```bash
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,mongodb_server_ip
```

Next, you can check if a user exists by following these [steps](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/list-users/):

Open up the mongo shell and type:

```
use admin
db.system.users.find()
```

If you really want to use "root"/"admin" user, make sure to specify the authSource in the URI by adding uri [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011332/authenticationfailed-to-mongodb-with-spring-boot) to your application's configuration file:
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<username>:<password>@:/<db-name>?authSource=admin

However, I highly recommend creating a new user dedicated to your database. To create such a user, simply follow these steps in the mongosh:

1. Switch to the desired database using the command: use <database-name>
2. Create a new user by running the command:

```
db.createUser({ 
    user: "<username>",
    pwd: "<password>",
    roles: [
        { role: "userAdmin", db: "<database-name>" },
        { role: "dbAdmin", db: "<database-name>" },
        { role: "readWrite", db: "<database-name>" }
    ]
  }
);
```

Please note that the roles "dbAdmin" and "userAdmin" might not be necessary for your specific use case. If you're interested in learning more about MongoDB roles, you can find additional information [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/).

Once you've created a user with the desired roles, you can easily add it into your application.yml file like this:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: <host>
      port: <port>
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
      database: <database-name>
```