# Authentication Failed to mongodb code 18 with springboot 3

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to mongodb through springboot 3 it work perfectly and gives no error, but when I'm trying to insert/save document to db it produce this error

````
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:205) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:443) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:365) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:102) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:224) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    ... 62 common frames omitted```
````

this is my springboot configuration file and docker-compose

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8400
spring:
  application:
    name: notification-service
  kafka:
    bootstrap:
      servers: https://localhost:9092
  data:
    mongodb:
      username: "root"
      password: "example"
      host: "localhost"
      port: 27017
      database: "notification"
      authentication-database: "admin"
      #uri: mongodb://root:example@127.0.0.1:27017/notification?authSource=admin (I tried uri but didnt work as it was provided solution on stackoverflow)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: mexpress
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: mexpress
volumes:
  mongodb:
```

I have followed this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011332/authenticationfailed-to-mongodb-with-spring-boot) but it didn't help, also I followed this problem on springboot [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34450) but it did not solve it for me.

So does any one knows how to solve it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems correct. And the user that you are using has all privileges.

Check if the Database "notification" exist and try first to create documents and delete in a specific collection within the "notification" database with mongoexpress by using the same user and see if you have any error.